# Race conditions on querying on a dataset that is currently on edit

Tags: postgresql

**PostgreSQL 10.4**

I have a huge database. It needs cleaning. For example, now I'm cleaning duplicate records. Delete command have been working for about 24 hours and is still working.

The command was:

```
delete from phrases where phrases.id not in (select id from (select distinct on (title) * from phrases) as phrases_id);
```

The question is not about the effectiveness of my command.

After delection of duplicates I'll continue cleaning using big lists of minus words. Well, anyway it will always be delete commannd. And I don't begin a transaction.

Let us suppose that any command will work for more than a day.  And meanwhile I'd like to clean other unnecessary records.

Please, have a look at the picture. Let us suppose that set A is duplicates. It is now being deleted. And meanwhile I'd like to delete set B.

I have a suspicion that it may interfere with the deletion of set A. Could you tell me whether my fears are reasonable or I can freely delete any record while other delete command is working in the background?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your isolation level. But if it is default there shouldn't be any problems. Because the MVCC / isolation level concept creates a snapshot of the data for every SELECT.

From the Postgres documentation:

> Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR UPDATE/SHARE clause) sees only data committed before the query began; it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during query execution by concurrent transactions. In effect, a SELECT query sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to run.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/mvcc-intro.html

So A is deleting data on its own data set snapshot. Because it is not yet commited B creates a snapshot of the "origin" data and is working on it.

Then A comes to its end, commits the transaction of its snapshot, no problem. Same with B. The only problem here is that you might delete one row doubled which could be a performance issue.